# If a graph G of order $n \geq 4 $ has minimum degree of at least $\frac{n-1}{2}$, then prove that G cannot have a bridge.

Tags: graph-theory

It was suggested that I solve this by contradiction.
I tried suggesting that if G had a bridge then there would be a contradiction on the order of G but this was obviously unsuccessful:
Assume G has some bridge, e. Then deleting e from G would yield a graph with 2 connected components. e joins two vertices in each component and each of these vertices has minimum degree $\frac{n-1}{2}$ in G, thus there must be at least $\frac{n-1}{2}-1+1$ vertices in each component of G-e. This result doesn't yield a contradiction so I'm assuming I have to take some other approach. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $n$?. Question appears incomplete.

Comment: Sorry updated the question

Comment: Again I'm sorry. I just updated it with the other requirement that n>=4 right as you commented.

Comment: Would a minimum degree of $\frac{n-1}2$ imply that $n$ is odd?

Comment: Again my wording has been confusing. It should say a minimum degree of at least $\frac{n-1}{2}$. Sorry for all these silly mistakes.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188770/if-g-is-a-graph-having-p-vertices-and-min-degree-deltag-ge-fracp-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing any edge $e\in G$, the two vertices adjacent to $e$ each has at least degree $\frac{n-1}{2}-1 > 0$, so any connected component with a vertex adjacent to $e$ has at least one other vertex not adjacent to $e$.

For each vertex not adjacent to $e$, its degree is at least $\frac{n-1}2$ before and after removing $e$. That means any connected component with such vertex has at least $\frac{n-1}{2}+1 = \frac{n+1}2$ vertices.

If there are $k$ components in graph $G\setminus\{e\}$, then the total number of vertices $n$ is

$$\begin{align*}
n &\ge k\cdot \frac{n+1}{2}\\
k &\le 2 - \frac{2}{n+1} < 2
\end{align*}$$

So $G\setminus\{e\}$ is connected for any $e$, which means there are no bridges in $G$.

(This also shows that $G$ must be connected, even before removing any $e$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!